# Why I get Unknown column in 'field list' for a primary key value ? [PHP + MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting a very annoying error that I'm unable to solve. I inserted various `echo` statements figure out what's going on, despite that I haven't managed to solve it. Let's jump to the PHP code:

```
class Payment extends DAO {
    private $table = "fss_Payment";

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct($this->table);
    }

    public function addPayment($totalAmount){
        $queryAddPayment = sprintf("
        INSERT
        INTO
          fss_Payment(amount, paydate, shopid, ptid)
        VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"
            , $totalAmount
            , date("Y-m-d")
            , 1
            , 2
        );

      echo $queryAddPayment;
      parent::query($queryAddPayment);
    }

    public function getPayment(){
      $queryGetPayment = "
        SELECT
          payid
        FROM
          fss_Payment
        ORDER BY
          payid DESC
        LIMIT 1
      ";

        $e = new \Exception;
        var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());

      return parent::query($queryGetPayment);
    }

    public function addAndGetPayment($totalAmount){
      $this->addPayment($totalAmount);
      return $this->getPayment()->fetch_assoc();
    }
}
?>
```

The error is in the getPayment() method, the query return an error: Unknown column 'payid' in 'field list, despite the table has a payid field.

Also I can see that the fields are correctly inserted, the problem is retrieving that queries. Thanks for your help.

[image: Query]
[image: Field]

Comment: Test the query in phpmyadmin to be sure it is working fine.

Comment: Yes, If I run the query on phpmyadmin the query works fine and return the last element in the table as expected.

Comment: This may affect sometimes so can you try with query on one line.$queryGetPayment = "SELECT payid FROM fss_Payment ORDER BY payid DESC LIMIT 1";

Comment: Doesn't help unfortunately

Comment: Ok double check if you are connected to the right database.

Comment: Yes I'm on the right database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213194/discussion-between-ibrahim-and-webstormer).